# DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body DICT_TYPE_CONVERT: Only dictionaries may be used in a DictType

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou fazendo um bot para discord com Node.js e discord.js. Quando fui fazer o comando de erro, ocorre o erro que está no título:

> DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body DICT_TYPE_CONVERT: Only dictionaries may be used in a DictType

Código:

```js
    client.on('message', function(msg) {
        if (msg.content.startsWith(config.prefix) || !msg.author.bot) {
            const user = msg.member;
            const args = msg.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(' ');
            const command = args.shift();
            var mentionedUser = msg.mentions.members.first();
            if (command === 'ban' && user.hasPermission('BAN_MEMBERS')) {
                mentionedUser.ban(args.join()).then(function() {
                    msg.reply(mentionedUser.toString() + ' banido com sucesso!');
                }).catch(function(e) {
                    msg.reply('Não foi possível banir ' + mentionedUser.toString() + ' devido ao seguinte erro: ' + e);
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pela [documentação](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=ban) `.ban` espera estes argumentos nesse formato específico:

```
guildMember.ban({ days: 7, reason: 'They deserved it' })
```

Tente passar as informações neste mesmo formato, isso deve resolver seu problema